# angular ng-repeat with directive

Tags: angularjs, charts, angularjs-ng-repeat, directive

i'm new to angular and have the following issue where i need assistence.
I'm using angular charts directives http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/ to build a chart board. I got the follwoing scenario:

I have a directive  a view and anenter code here associated controller.
Inside the controller there should be an array charts[] which holds objects.
these objects should be two-way binded with the chart directive.
What is the appropriate way to do so? I will bild my charts dynamically without any controller attached to each chart. Is that possible?

### reportView.html

```
<div ng-repeat="c in charts">
<chart></chart>
<div>
```

### reportViewController.js

```
angular.module('app').controller('reportViewController', reportViewCtrl);

reportViewCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$log', 'RefinerService', 'appConfig'];


function reportViewCtrl($scope, $log, RefinerService, appConfig) {
    $scope.charts = [];
    var chart = {
                ID: 1
                , Visible: true
                , Type: "chart-line"
                , Data: [
                    [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
                    , [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
                ]
                    , Labels: ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012']
                    , Series: ['Product A', 'Product B']

    }
    $scope.charts.push(chart);
}
```

### chartTemplate.html

```
<div class="chart-container" flex>
<canvas class="chart {{c.Type}}" 
  data="{{c.Data}}" 
  labels="{{c.Labels}}" 
  series="{{c.Series}}">
</canvas>
</div>
```

### directive.js

```
angular.module('app').directive('chart', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templates/chartTemplate.html',
        scope: {
            id: '@id',
            type: '@type'
        }
    };
});
```

help would be appreciated! cheers philipp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Final fiddle showing working example, in collaboration with OP - https://plnkr.co/edit/8fJ4u0U2fL4lYTioCbG0?p=preview

You need to pass the "c" from the ng-repeat into the chart directive.

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/8zwmt18L/1/

```
<div ng-repeat="c in charts">
<chart chart-data="c"></chart>
<div>
```

In your directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('chart', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templates/chartTemplate.html',
        scope: {
            chartData: '='
        }
    };
});
```

In your directive template:

```
<div class="chart-container" flex>
<canvas class="chart chart-base" 
  chart-type="chartData.Type"
  data="chartData.Data" 
  labels="chartData.Labels" 
  series="chartData.Series">
</canvas>
</div>
```

In the data for the charts, your types will need to be "Line" or "Bar", and not "chart-line" or "chart-bar"

Comment: Here is my Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/ahIHQFCpmInk7UsO2WJX?p=preview - unfortunately it's not working for me -.- do you know what's wrong? Thank You Sooo Much for your great help!

Comment: Hurrah! That was confusing. You have to define a base css of chart-base and then set the chart-type as the type, and that is then not "chart-line" but simply "Line". https://plnkr.co/edit/8fJ4u0U2fL4lYTioCbG0?p=preview

Comment: There are some subtle nuances to using angular chart and the way binding appears to work, so we can omit the `{{}}` when binding the data/label/series/type